# Salesforce case routing to 2 queues based on availability

Tags: case, assignment-rules, web2case

any help is really appreciated!
We are routing cases to agents and we have a small issue with the queue prioritization.

a-Cases are coming from the web in Language X (not English)

b-Based on the Language X we assign the case to the queue with agents that speak the X language

c-These X Language queue agents, are not available always as they have their business hours that are only 9-5.

**Issue: If it's outside 9-5, the cases should be routed to the English queue that is always available 24/7.**

What would be the best way to implement this considering that we are also using Omnichannel?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that executes prior to assignment rules that you have control over is a `before insert` trigger.

If said trigger can detect the language and the time of day in the relevant timezone (which it should be able to do), you can set a custom field `RoutingAssistant_IsNonEnglishOutsideOfBusinessHours__c` to true and use that in your assignment rules

You can't use process builder or workflow as those execute after the assignment rules have already run